# Creating a DB aware component - TFieldDataLink.Edit causes fields to reload

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3

I am trying to create a data aware control.  I have a TFieldDataLink object with a DataSource and Field hooked up. Everything seemed to be going OK until I tried to edit the value.

I am using the OnDataChange and OnUpdateData events for the TFieldDataLink.  It looks like I need to call TFieldDataLink.Edit if I want the OnUpdateData event to be called before moving to a new record or posting.  In the sample code below am trying to call .Edit in the OnExit field of the control if changes were made.  In my actual app the control consists of several DevExpress lookup combo boxes and I am trying to call .Edit in OnEditValueChanged.

My problem is the call to TFieldDataLink.Edit causes the OnDataChange event to fire again.  That forces a reload of my edit with the original value.  If I make a second change after the Dataset is already in edit mode then a OnDataChange event is not fired.

Here is a test unit I that has everything on one form.  In my actual app this is split out into a more complicated component.

When should I be calling .Edit without getting OnUpdateData to change?  I know I could set a member variable to stop the reload or unhook the events before calling .Edit.  It feels like there is something I don't understand about the TFieldDataLink object and I should not need to resort to those tricks.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, uADStanIntf, uADStanOption, uADStanParam, uADStanError,
  uADDatSManager, uADPhysIntf, uADDAptIntf, Data.DB, uADCompDataSet, uADCompClient, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.DBCtrls, Vcl.Mask, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    ADMemTable1: TADMemTable;
    ADMemTable1test: TStringField;
    Button1: TButton;
    DBEdit1: TDBEdit;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FMyDataLink: TFieldDataLink;
    procedure MyDataChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyUpdateData(Sender: TObject);
  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdMemTable1.CreateDataSet;

  FMyDataLink := TFieldDataLink.Create();
  FMyDataLink.DataSource := DataSource1;
  FMyDataLink.FieldName := 'test';

  FMyDataLink.OnDataChange := MyDataChange;
  FMyDataLink.OnUpdateData := MyUpdateData;


  AdMemTable1.Append;
  AdMemTable1.FieldByName('test').AsString := 'my test';
  AdMemTable1.Post;


end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyDataLink.OnDataChange := nil;
  FMyDataLink.OnUpdateData := nil;
  FMyDataLink.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Edit1.Modified = true then
  begin
    FMyDataLink.Edit;
    FMyDataLink.Modified;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.MyDataChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := FMyDataLink.Field.AsString;
  Edit1.Modified := false;
end;


procedure TForm1.MyUpdateData(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyDataLink.Field.AsString := Edit1.Text
end;


end.
```

Answer (score 2):

[`TFieldDataLink.Edit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TFieldDataLink.Edit) only sets the DataSource in editing state (just like `DataSet.Edit`). You do not need it here, but example usage could be:

```
procedure TMyCustomControl.DoPaste;
begin
  FMyDataLink.Edit;
  inherited DoPaste;
  FMyDataLink.Modified;
end;
```

What you want instead on exit of the control is to update the record, if it is modified:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Edit1.Modified then
    try
      FMyDataLink.UpdateRecord;
    except
      Edit1.SetFocus;
      raise;
    end;
end;
```

As for when [`TFieldDataLink.Modified`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TFieldDataLink.Modified) should be called, that's when you have updated the field value:

```
procedure TForm1.MyUpdateData(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyDataLink.Field.AsString := Edit1.Text;
  FMyDataLink.Modified;
end;
```

Comment: If you call FMyDataLink.UpdateRecord without calling FMyDataLink.Edit first the UpdateData events are never called so the Dataset never gets updated.  I don't want to immediately put the Dataset into edit mode.  I want to wait until the first change is made like other db components do.  I just can't figure out how to not lose that first change.

Comment: If in the `OnExit` handler, `FMyDataLink.Modified` isn't already called, then thát's your problem. `OnExit` does not need to signal there's something changed; that responsibility lies with e.g. the `OnChange` handler of the Edit.

Comment: Still does not work.  Setting Modified only seems to ensure that UpdateData is called for that field.  And that only happens if Edit is called, which is right back to my problem that calling edit after the first change causes a reload.  In the case of an TEdit if I put a call to DataLink.Edit in the OnChange event and I try to type a letter at the end of the field my edit is cleared in the reload and the cursor is moved back to the front of the text.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but for those who are encountering the same problem,
you have to override the data-aware control's KeyPress method and call the FieldDataLink.Edit; after Inherited; if the Key is valid for the input (incl. del/c&p/bs/etc..). 
At this point the current data is not yet modified. Calling .Edit later than this point is too late.